# bitbake error in do_rootfs: systemd depends on update-rc.d

Tags: yocto, systemd, bitbake

I got a bit stuck debugging a yocto build problem. I encountered this while updating from yocto warrior (2.7) to yocto dunfell (3.1) The build fails during the building of the rootfs, all steps before seem to work:

```sh
    ERROR: my-project-develop-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install base-version-develop bash cairo cantarell-fonts cellular-geolocation commit-hashes-develop crda curl disable-airplane-mode disable-power-saving-for-some-devices disconnect-wifi-without-connectivity dnsmasq dosfstools e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-resize2fs firmware-develop fit-conf gbs-overlay geofencing-db hostapd htop i2c-tools iw jq lateswap libgpiod libgpiod-tools linux-firmware-rtl8192cu matlab-develop modemmanager mosquitto mosquitto-clients nano network-configuration networkmanager openmoji-fonts os-release ostree ostree-devicetrees ostree-initramfs ostree-kernel packagegroup-base packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-openssh parted psplash-raspberrypi pstree raspi-gpio rtwpriv run-postinsts set-modes-and-bands source-han-sans-jp-fonts special-shadow sqlite3tzdata u-boot-fw-utils userland weston weston-init wifi-configurator-frontend-develop wifilm811 wifilm843 wpa-supplicant locale-base-en-us' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.2.2
cachedir: /shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /shared/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi_cm3-poky-linux-gnueabi/my-project-develop/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for:
not found modules for:
not found deltainfo for:
not found updateinfo for:
oe-repo: using metadata from Tue 16 Feb 2021 08:59:38 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error:
 Problem 1: package packagegroup-core-boot-1.0-r17.raspberrypi_cm3 requires systemd, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides update-rc.d needed by systemd-1:244.5-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4
 Problem 2: package packagegroup-distro-base-1.0-r83.raspberrypi_cm3 requires packagegroup-core-boot, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package packagegroup-base-1.0-r83.raspberrypi_cm3 requires packagegroup-distro-base, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package packagegroup-core-boot-1.0-r17.raspberrypi_cm3 requires systemd, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides update-rc.d needed by systemd-1:244.5-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4
 Problem 3: package packagegroup-base-1.0-r83.raspberrypi_cm3 requires packagegroup-distro-base, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package packagegroup-distro-base-1.0-r83.raspberrypi_cm3 requires packagegroup-core-boot, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package packagegroup-base-extended-1.0-r83.raspberrypi_cm3 requires packagegroup-base, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package packagegroup-core-boot-1.0-r17.raspberrypi_cm3 requires systemd, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides update-rc.d needed by systemd-1:244.5-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

It seems that `systemd-1:244.5` depends on `update-rc.d`. This doesn't make a lot sense to me, since I don't need those scripts anymore when using systemd - maybe there are for some compatibility reasons? Puzzled by this I checked [the reference](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#selecting-an-initialization-manager) and it seems that I have the right settings to use systemd exclusively:

```
$ bitbake -e exos-develop | grep "^DISTRO_FEATURES"
DISTRO_FEATURES="acl alsa argp bluetooth ext2 ipv4 ipv6 largefile pcmcia usbgadget usbhost wifi xattr nfs zeroconf pci 3g nfc x11 vfat largefile opengl ptest multiarch wayland vulkan systemd weston wayland  sota usrmerge systemd systemd pulseaudio gobject-introspection-data ldconfig"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL="pulseaudio sysvinit gobject-introspection-data ldconfig"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED="sysvinit sysvinit"
DISTRO_FEATURES_DEFAULT="acl alsa argp bluetooth ext2 ipv4 ipv6 largefile pcmcia usbgadget usbhost wifi xattr nfs zeroconf pci 3g nfc x11 vfat"
DISTRO_FEATURES_FILTER_NATIVE="api-documentation"
DISTRO_FEATURES_FILTER_NATIVESDK="api-documentation"
DISTRO_FEATURES_NATIVE="x11 ipv6 xattr sota"
DISTRO_FEATURES_NATIVESDK="x11"
```

During debugging I also saw that [poky's systemd recipe](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-boot_244.5.bb?h=dunfell) uses the [update-rc.d.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/update-rc.d.bbclass). From what I can see it only gets active when the `DISTRO_FEATURES` contain `sysvinit`, which is apparently not the case here. Maybe some caching issue?

Any ideas how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out myself (interesting how asking questions helps you thinking...):

The issue was in the `systemd` recipe itself and related to the `systemd-compat-units` recipe. I was able to fix it with this in my layer's `recipes-core/systemd/systemd_%.bbappend`:

```
# Disable all relations to update-rc.d:
PACKAGECONFIG_remove = "sysvinit"
RRECOMMENDS_${PN}_remove = "systemd-compat-units"
```

I'm still wondering how this issue came to be at all, though.
Would be great if somebody could explain why this happened at all.